# vba For each loop writing to the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to reach out on a concern i am getting with with my loop. i need to copy all trainee data in the class list sheet from rows 13 on and put it into a roster registry sheet same workbook. however the code i wrote initially is giving me and error when i use .Range(i, 1) so i changed it to .Cells. Main concern is that the code writes the data into the roster registry sheet but only the last trainee data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportcReg()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim s1, cReg As Worksheet
Dim x, i, FinalRow As Long
Dim thisvalue As String
Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("A1").Value)
Set s1 = wbk1.Sheets("ClassRegistry")
Set cReg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Class Registry")

With cReg
    ' Find the last row of data in Column "A"
    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        ' Decide if to copy based on column A
        thisvalue = .Cells(x, 1).Value
        If thisvalue <> "" Then
            i = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            s1.Cells(i, 1).Value = thisvalue
            s1.Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(x, 2).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 3).Value = .Cells(x, 3).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 4).Value = .Cells(x, 4).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 5).Value = .Cells(x, 5).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 6).Value = .Cells(x, 5).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 7).Value = .Cells(x, 7).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 8).Value = .Cells(x, 8).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 9).Value = .Cells(x, 9).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 10).Value = .Cells(x, 10).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 11).Value = .Cells(x, 11).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 12).Value = .Cells(x, 12).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 13).Value = .Cells(x, 13).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 14).Value = .Cells(x, 14).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 15).Value = .Cells(x, 15).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 16).Value = .Cells(x, 16).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 17).Value = .Cells(x, 17).Value
            s1.Cells(i, 18).Value = .Cells(x, 18).Value
        End If
    Next x
End With
wbk1.Close savechanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Variable `i` is not changing, so data is writing over the previous: you see only last one. Try something as `k=1`, `ws2.Cells(k, 8).Value`, and `k=k+1`. Anyway, it's not clear to me what you pretend to do.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. What i need to do is copy each trainee information from rows 13 and below on the class list sheet and copy them into the roster registry sheet but i need it to look for the first empty row  and start writing there.

Comment: One of your problems is Cells(0, 1). You are referring to a row number 0 which does not exits.

Answer (score 0):

You have too much logical and technical errors in your code which I cannot explain line by line. Besides you can achieve your goal with less coding. Maybe what you need is a working code to understand how things work. Take a look at this:

```
Sub CListtoRReg()
 'From Class List to Roster Registry
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("Class List")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("Roster Registry")
    Dim i, j As Long
    For i = 13 To ws1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
           ws2.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1) = ws1.Range("C2").Value
       For j = 2 To 11
           ws2.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, j - 1) = ws1.Cells(i, j - 1).Value
       Next j
    Next i
 End Sub
```